# Unable to think about a quiz question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

I am asking about a quiz question which I am trying to solve but not able to think about. Please note any number of options in it can be true.

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^{\infty}$-function.

Suppose that for every $x\in U$, the derivative ad $x$, $df_x$, is non singular.
Then which of the following statements are true?

1. If $V\subset U$ is open then $f(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$
2. $f:U\to f(U)$ is a homeomorphism
3. $f$ is one-one
4. If $V\subset U$ is closed, then $f(V)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

What I thought -> since first order derivative is non singular, so $f$ is 1-1 . But I am unable to think about any of other options .

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $f$ is locally invertible thanks to the inverse function theorem, and thus it's an open map
2. This is not true, as shown by the counterexample $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos(y), e^x \sin(y))$
3. The counterexample in 2 is enough.
4. False, as shown by the $f(x)=e^x:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+_0$

That 2 is false shows how weak the inverse function theorem is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, compared to the one-dimensional case: it can only be considered locally, while on $\mathbb{R}$ it is quite easy to extend. In particular, if $f$ is $C^1(U)$ and its derivative is non-singular, $f$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, and thus its invertible

As a note, the counterexample in $2$ is quite an easy one to think of, if it is seen in a complex analytic setting: as a function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=e^z$, which is analytic(and thus $C^\infty$), its derivative is non zero but its inverse is multivalued

Comment: thanks a lot for such a nice explaination.